# Avoiding repetition in this SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I'm using SQLite to modify and error-check data that isn't easily accessible via the GUI, out of an Adobe program. Unusually helpfully for Adobe, they're using absolutely standard SQLite 3 db so it's easy.

The output from SQLite Studio (the GUI based program I'm using) is cut/pasted into Excel, so I'm also using the query to automate the heavy preprocessing/sorting/grouping/evaluations/error functions that I'd otherwise have to do each time in Excel.

My query needs to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
SELECT

record_id,
(several lines of CASE-WHEN, IF, and other logic) 
    as record_type,
(several almost identical lines of CASE-WHEN, IF, and other logic)
    as record_subtype

FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY record_id
```

The thing is, I need to reference [record_type] in the logic for [record_subtype].

I could use nested queries or subqueries (I'm familiar with both), or even an in-memory temporary table. But to keep the output fields' code simple, **is there a way to directly reference [record_type] *(which has already been calculated)* when evaluating [record_subtype]**?

If not, how would I do it with an in-memory table or would it usually be faster to use a nested query?